# bluemix shell doesn't respond to typing and has no prompt

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've enabled the debugging for my bluemix application and can even debug it using the chrome debugger.  When I click on "Open Shell" from the bluemix developer console, I get the /bluemix-debug/shell page with the NEW WINDOW button which opens a terminal-looking frame with a blinking cursor, but typing anything doesn't show up in the frame and there's no prompt showing either.

Comment: Are you using Chrome as a web browser for this? It is buggy for me sometimes in Chrome - try Firefox. It works well for me with that browser.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome.  Tried using Firefox and got same result.

Comment: Can you post your browser version, and operating system version? And also try again with any cookie or script blocking mechanisms in your browser disabled.

Comment: Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit); Mac OS X 10.11.2; I don't believe I have any cookie or script blocking enabled.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your browser is the issue. I have a Mac and can access it on Chrome and Firefox. The terminal shell uses tty.js (https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/) and web sockets. Look into anything that might be blocking that, and try different browsers. Post your solution if you find anything.

Comment: sorry.. I deleted some comments.  I was copying and pasting commands that had a typo in them, but I fixed that and now have successfully done the 'cf api', 'cf se' and 'cf restage' command.  Debugger works, but still can't get shell to work on either Chrome or FF.  I'm using FF 43.0.4.  I'll update to 44.0.1

Comment: upgrading to FF 44.0.1 didn't fix it.  Probably something in firewall??

Comment: That would be my guess. Are you change networks and try debugging on a different network? You could also test websocket function on your network with a tool like http://www.websocket.org/echo.html, but those tests can be unreliable.

Comment: When I start the debugger from Chrome, I see this error in the console tab: Error: Cannot find module '/home/vcap/app/.app-management/handlers/start-inspector/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-debug/build/debug/v0.5.4/node-v46-linux-x64/debug.node'

Comment: Could you correct the typo in your last message?  I don't understand "Are you change networks and try debugging on a different network?".

Comment: Doing the test at websocket.org/echo.html works fine.  I even think the debugger uses websockets and that works.  (Well it works while actively using it, it must time out cause when I don't use the debugger for awhile, I get a message "Detached from the target, Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: websocket_closed.  Please re-attach to the new target".